# Does the Grand Magic Games have referees?

Tags: fairy-tail

The Grand Magic Games was said to be around for years, but they don't seem to have any referees. They don't have anyone who's able to sense that someone from the crowd got rid of Lucy's spell and, that was a huge one.

What's to stop a guild from having a bunch of people uses support magic on one of their wizards while they're in battle?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the pumpkin head (the king) was the referee for the Grand Magic Games that we see, but generally, the guilds that compete aren't Dark Guilds, so they don't have a reason for sabotage.

Raven Tail was just an exception, and one of the judges (the former council member) told the guest judge (council lacky) to keep a close eye on Raven Tail.

Also, there are no rules about torturing, so Lucy vs. Minerva fight was considered a Minerva's win.

Comment: just because they aren't a dark guild it doesn't mean that they don't want to win so a super competitive team (cough) Sabertooth (cough) would have a reason to either sabotage another team or support their own team